# How to manage clustered mode of Quartz jobs in runtime?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am running Quartz job in clustered mode. Here is my config. Is it possible to change node of job runtime (JMX RMI)?

For example my server has 2 nodes. First is too busy so I need to change job to second one.

```xml
<property name="quartzProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">myApp</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">60000</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">q</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export">true</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName">quartz:type=QuartzScheduler,name=JmxScheduler,instanceId=NONE_CLUSTER</prop>
    </props>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly.  I don't think choosing the server that a job runs on is part of the standard version of Quartz.  It is available in [Quartz Scheduler Where](http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/quartz-scheduler/quartz-scheduler-where).

If you want to proceed with RMI, you could probably write a program that turns off one of the schedulers in the cluster based on conditional logic (if you disable the job, it would prevent future execution on all servers).  From [the manual](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigRMI):

> When using Quartz via RMI, you need to start an instance of Quartz
>   with it configured to "export" its services via RMI. You then create
>   clients to the server by configuring a Quartz scheduler to "proxy" its
>   work to the server.

To turn on RMI:

`<prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export">true</prop>`

[This page from O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/quartz.html?page=4) describes the entire process in detail and shows an example of managing a remote instance from a client.  Modify their example to turn off the scheduler.

If you're open to an off-the-shelf solution, the [MySchedule project](http://code.google.com/p/myschedule/wiki/Faq#How_can_I_manage_remote_Quartz_using_MySchedule_?) is a web-based UI for managing Quartz.  It's capable of managing remote instances.

An alternate approach is to manage the synchronization outside of Quartz.  Allow the jobs to fire on all of the nodes, but use your own logic within the job to determine whether the current node should actually do any processing.  You could use JGroups or a similar library to communicate load information between nodes.

Lastly, have you considered that Quartz might not be the right tool for the job?  It sounds like a distributed queue might be appropriate.  For example, a set of competing clients pull work items from a queue as quickly as they can process them.